# Configuration is empty

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to read config data from `appsettings.json`, which looks like this:

```
{
    Owner: {
        Name: "Dave",
        City: "Dusseldorf"
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs I have:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

In my class I have

```
private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

public MyClass(
    IConfiguration configuration
    )
{
    _configuration = configuration;
}
```

...and later in the same class

```
string name= _configuration["Owner.Name"];
```

But this is always empty.
However, if I add a breakpoint on that line and expand the _configuration class I can see a list of `Providers (Count = 5)` including one for `appsettings.json`, and if I expand this I can see my setting values, including `Name`.

However these don't seem to be accessible from code.

Am I using the wrong class/namespace? How should I read these values?

Comment: Design issue. Shouldn't really be injecting `IConfiguration` out side of startup. Show what you actually want to achieve and an answer can be provided. Also include example of of the settings file

Comment: Edited. Confused - what should I be doing instead then? I don't want to do anything special, just read the values from config.

Comment: I understood config values were accessed with a colon separating the sections. Did you try `_configuration["Owner:Name"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be more of a design issue. Shouldn't really be injecting `IConfiguration` out side of `Startup`.

Consider creating a POCO model of the desired configuration.

```
public class MyClassOptions {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And have the target class depend on that strongly typed model

```
public class MyClass {

    private readonly MyClassOptions options;

    public MyClass(MyClassOptions options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public void SomeMethod() {
        string name = options.Name;
        string city = options.City;

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

In `Startup` access the configuration as shown before but extract the desired configuration details.

```
public class Startup {
    IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Startup() {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        //Bind to object graph from configuration
        MyClassOptions options = Configuration.GetSection("Owner").Get<MyClassOptions>();
        //make it available to the service collection for Dependency Injection
        services.AddSingleton<MyClassOptions>(options);


        services.AddTransient<MyClass>();

        //...
    }
}
```

When `MyClass` is resolved, the options extracted from configuration will be injected.

This way the target class is not tightly coupled to framework details.

Comment: As tymtam above says, this is not my entire code - I had simplified it for the question. I am actually using a POCO class and it's that class that is trying to read config. However I have now resolved this issue; I was using dots as section delimiters rather than colons - it works now! Thanks.

Comment: @CompanyDroneFromSector7G understood. My suggestion about not not coupling to `IConfiguration` still applies. Check updated answer based on your update to question.

Answer (score 3):

One of the worst reasons this can happen is that your appsettings.json is not built (copied into the bin folder). Try **right-clicking** the file -> select **properties** and set to **Copy if newer** or **Copy Always**. That would make sure the file is properly copied and found by the configuration logic.

Comment: This won't happen. If the json file cannot be found, an exception will be thrown. Like `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'The configuration file 'app1settings.Development.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was 'D:\MyProject\app1settings.Development.json'.'`

Answer (score 1):

The configuration built via builder build needs to be added to available services.

```
var configuration = builder.Build(); 
services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);
```

Please note that your not showing us your real code (I.e Startup would not complie, it's missing return type declaration, we don't know what `Configuration` is) so I'm making guesses about your setup.